# $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly increasing function, such that, $0<f(x)<1$ and $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1+f^2(x)}$. Then $g$ is also increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given the strictly monotonic function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $0<f( x)< 1$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g$ a function such that $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1+f^2(x)}$. Prove that the function $g$ has the same type of monotonicity as $f$.

Here is what I did so far: I need to prove this using the definition pf a monotonic function since I don't know if f or g are differentiable. Let $f$ be strictly increasing. Then, for every $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1 <x_2$, we have $f(x_{1})<f(x_{2})$. Also, $0<f(x)<1 \Rightarrow 0<f^2(x)<1$ and also $0<f^2(x)<f(x)<1$, for all $x$. Now, for $g$:  $g(x_1)= \frac{f(x_1)}{1+f^2(x_1)} < \frac{f(x_2)}{1+f^2(x_1)} < \frac{f(x_2)}{1+0} = f(x_2)$, and I cannot see how to build $g(x_2)$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint : Show that $y \mapsto \frac{y}{1+y^2}$ is strictly increasing on $(0,1)$.

Comment: So, let $h(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$, $h'(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$ that is positive on $(0,1)$, hence, the composition of two increasing functiions, $h\circ f(x)$, is also increasing. Thank you. Is there any way to show that $h$ is increasing on $(0,1)$ using the definition?

Comment: I figured it out using Eugene's answer. Let $0<x_1<x_2<1$, then $f(x_2)-f(x_1)=\frac{x_2}{1+x_{2}^{2}}-\frac{x_1}{1+x_{1}^{2}} \Rightarrow (1+x_{2}^{2})(1+x_{1}^{2})(f(x_2)-f(x_1)) = x_2-x_1$. Since $ (1+x_{2}^{2}),(1+x_{1}^{2}), x_2-x_1$ are all positive, then $f(x_2)-f(x_1)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\forall x_1, x_2 ∈ \mathbb{R}$, such that $x_1 < x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ (or $f(x_1)-f(x_2) < 0$).

Now, let us consider

$$
\begin{aligned}
g(x_1)-g(x_2) &= \frac{f(x_1)}{1+f^2(x_1)}-\frac{f(x_2)}{1+f^2(x_2)} = \\
&= \frac{f(x_1) + f(x_1)f^2(x_2) - f(x_2)-f(x_2)f^2(x_1)}{(1+f^2(x_1))(1+f^2(x_2))} = \\
&= \frac{(f(x_1)-f(x_2))(1-f(x_1)f(x_2))}{(1+f^2(x_1))(1+f^2(x_2))} = \\
&= \left[
\begin{array}{l}
\text{the denominator is always positive and doesn't affect the sign of the expression.} \\
\text{in the numerator we have}: f(x_1) - f(x_2) < 0; \:  0 < 1-f(x_1)f(x_2) < 1. 
\end{array}
\right]  \\
&<0.
\end{aligned}
$$